# Typescript import using path from some root

Tags: typescript, angular

Is there any simple way to set up so that I can `import` starting from some root point?

e.g.:

```
- module1
   \- file1.ts
- module2
   \- file2.ts
```

in file2 i want to `import` file1

```
import { foo } from '../module1/file1'
```

What I would like to do instead is something like:

```
import { foo } from 'src/module1/file1'
```

Angular2 somehow uses this (see https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/core/compiler/compiler.ts). I looked into their build process, but it's so complex, I'm not sure how they enabled this.

Answer (score 1):

All ES6 imports are relative, angular2 are using systemjs to handle all the imports/exports. And in the systemjs configuration you can define a map. (I wouldn't go there)

You have to remember that imports in ES6 are just loading javascript files, so if src is your root, you should be able to just import from **/src/module1/files**

Comment: My app is actually a node app, so typescript is transpiled to ES5 and require. I don't think you can import from root with require, unless you hack it somehow or force the compiler to generate correct relative path for you.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/app-module-path seems to be the best solution for node.

Update:

I use it like this

```
root
  \- module1
  |  \- file1.ts
  \- module2
  |  \- file2.ts
  \- main.ts
```

`main.ts` is entry point for the application, and these are the first two lines:

```
import * as path from 'path';

require('app-module-path').addPath(path.resolve(__dirname, '..'));
```

then from `module2/file2.ts` i can do this:

```
import { Stuff } from 'root/module1/file1';
```

Comment: Did you manage to get `app-module-path` to work? Because it does not work for me using it.

Comment: Yes, see updated answer. This worked for me for any version of node I ran.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will give it a try :))

Answer (score 1):

I am working with Angular CLI and the standard structure it produces.

So everything I work with is in `src/app`.

My main HTTP service is located at `src/app/services/httpService.ts`.

To get import this service I use:

```
import { HttpService } from 'app/services/httpService'
```

I'm not sure if this relies on any special config that Angular CLI does (and I realise Angular CLI wasn't around at the time this question was posted) but it would be worth a try in your environment.

Comment: This is a feature of typescript compiler, that has been improved a lot since this question, there is also a setting where you can configure custom paths (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html). Also there are (or used to be) some differences between node and browser module resolution.