# How does import work in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

I followed the QuickStart from Angular2. And I made the folder structure different compare to the tutorial. And I encounter an error that **cannot find module ...**.

I understand the cause of the error is **import** issue.

My folder structure:
[image]

I have export the `hero` interface in the hero.ts file. And I want to import this interface in `hero-detail.component.ts` file.

I had tried:

```
import {Hero} from '../app/hero';
import {Hero} from './hero';
import {Hero} from './app/hero';
```

None of these are working.

The system configure in the index.html

[image]

#### My Question is:

How does import work in Angular 2?

Comment: did you add the system configuration correctly? are you compiling your ts into js? I dont see js files in your file structure.

Comment: @Langley I just updated the picture of my folder structure, as you can see, all the file are converted to js file.

Comment: that's why it works now =), you were defaulting to js files: `defaultExtension: 'js'`

Comment: @Langley It is helpful. The reason that was not working because the templateUrl was wrong in the `hero-detail.component`. I want to know the general way to get the path for import file in Angular2. For example `import {Component} from 'angular2/core';` can import angular2. What if I change the location of angular2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Then you'd probably need something like

```
import {Hero} from '../hero';
```

Comment: can you explain how you come up with this solution. It works now. I want to understand the relative path and absolute path for this.

Comment: With the relative path you start at the importing file `../` is one level up, and then we are already where the imported file is and just add the name of the file without the `.ts` extension. Relative paths seem to be the default in TS (I'm not a TS developer). Here is a SO answer for "absolute" (package-root-relative) paths http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32191057/typescript-import-using-path-from-some-root

Answer (score 2):

It should be related to the configuration of SystemJS.

Do you have SystemJS file included in your main HTML file:

```
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
```

Do you configure SystemJS with the JS default extension:

```
<script>
  System.config({
    packages: {        
      app: {
        format: 'register',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
  (...)
</script>
```

With this, what Günter proposed shoud work!

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: I do have the system configure as you posted.

Answer (score 0):

To navigate "up":

```
import {Hero} from './../hero';
```